# Como comparar fecha hoy y otra fecha

Tags: python, date

Me encuentro tratando de compara dos fechas (fecha de hoy y cualquier otra fecha), pero una vez que se entra al ciclo while no sale, pues al parecer no se cumple la condicion y no entiendo por que. la verdad soy nueva y no he encontrado una solcuion, pues aunque se cumple la condicion no entra al if y no entiendo por que.

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now().date()

fechaStringInicial = input("Digite fecha de inicio: (aaaa-mm-dd)")
print("fecha de hoy", now)

dateFormatter = "%Y-%m-%d"
fecha_final=datetime.strptime(fechaStringInicial, dateFormatter)
fecha_date=fecha_final.date()
print("fecha final", fecha_date)



if str(now) == str(fecha_date):
  bandera = False
  while bandera == False:
   print("Error ingrese una fecha mayor a la acutal")
   fechaStringInicial = input("Digite fecha de inicio: (aaaa-mm-dd)")
   dateFormatter = "%Y-%m-%d"
   fecha_final=datetime.strptime(fechaStringInicial, dateFormatter)
   fecha_date=fecha_final.date()
   now = datetime.now().date()
   print("fecha final", fecha_date)
   print("fecha de hoy", now)
   print("Antes compara mayor que")
   if fecha_date > now:
    Bandera=True
```

Comment: solo haz `if fecha_date >= now:` pues solo se compara si es mayor pero si es igual no y cambia `Bandera=True` a `bandera=True` pues empieza con minuscula

Comment: Leyendo solo el código, es difícil decir qué es lo que no funciona bien. ¿Qué es lo que quieres lograr?

Comment: Gracias @Christian el error era eso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que comenta @Christian es verdad, el bucle es infinito porque usas dos variables distintas `Bandera`/`bandera`, bien podrías hacer que sean iguales o mejor... no usarlas:

```
if str(now) == str(fecha_date):
    while True:
        print("Error ingrese una fecha mayor a la acutal")
        fechaStringInicial = input("Digite fecha de inicio: (aaaa-mm-dd)")
        dateFormatter = "%Y-%m-%d"
        fecha_final=datetime.strptime(fechaStringInicial, dateFormatter)
        fecha_date=fecha_final.date()
        now = datetime.now().date()
        print("fecha final", fecha_date)
        print("fecha de hoy", now)
        print("Antes compara mayor que")
        if fecha_date > now:
            break
```

Simplemente has que el `while` sea siempre verdadero y en el momento que se cumpla que `fecha_date > now` se rompe el bucle con `break`
(esto no es mas que una recomendación pero si esto es un ejercicio donde uno de los parámetros es usar una "bandera" pues debes estar pendiente del nombre que le coloques~)